# can ffmpeg perform frame wise image calculations?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-editing

I would like to divide each frame of a video by an image that I would like to provide as an additional input. Can ffmpeg perform such image calculations? I could not find any examples.

This would be a kind of background correction. The input image is the background, for example the median of a large number of frames.
(often people use a backgroundSUBTRACTION, but I want to use division)

currently I am doing this in openCV and python. I process each frame like this:

(vidMed is the background image)

```
import cv2
vidIn=cv2.VideoCapture(input.avi)
vidOut=cv2.VideoVriter(output.avi)

while true
    ret, frame = vidIn.read()
    bgDiv=frame/vidMed
    vidOut.write(bgDiv)
```

I was hoping this may run faster using ffmpeg

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you explain in more detail or add images showing the desired result?

Comment: I hope I clarified my question with a code example. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Perhaps the [blend filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blend_002c-tblend) using the divide component mode will do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, blend works!

```
ffmpeg.exe 
-i videoIn.avi 
-i imageIn.avi 
-filter_complex "[1:0] setsar=sar=1 [1sared];[0:0][1sared]blend=all_mode='divide':repeatlast=1[int];
-out.avi
```

(imageIn.avi is just one frame)